# Filtered table in wordpress

Tags: php

I am Developing a alphabetical filter table in wordpress template. But filter is not working may be because of code below.

```
if($char)
{
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM teacher_directory where Name LIKE '$char%'", ARRAY_A  );
    $count = $results->num_rows;
    if($count >= 1)
{   
    //Printing the table here
}
```

In the above code `$char` is taking the letters but list is empty.

Comment: Try this: `$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM teacher_directory where Name LIKE '" . $char . "%'", ARRAY_A  );`

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd     It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ok I got my answer

```
if($char)
{
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM teacher_directory where Name LIKE '$char%'", ARRAY_A  );
   if(!empty($results))
   {   
         //Printing the table here
   }
}
```